# Trying to create a pair generator

Tags: ruby, algorithm, math, combinations, permutation

I'm trying to build a pair generator. It takes a list of six names, and generates pairs for the week (5 days), with as few replications as possible.

The minimum I've gotten my replicated pairs down to is 2 (so I have found 5 days of pairs, i.e. 15 total pair combinations, with only 2 identical sets).

My method:

```
# Start with individuals in an array
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
# Bisect the array
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6] => yields pair combinations [1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]
# Move the lower of the bisected arrays along
[1, 2, 3]
[6, 4, 5] => yields pair combinations [1, 6], [2, 4], [3, 5]
# Move along once more
[1, 2, 3]
[5, 6, 4] => yields pair combinations [1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 4]
# Since there are no more unique pair combinations, bisect each array again
(Array 1) [1, 2]
(Array 1) [3] => yields pair combination [1, 3] with 2 'spare'
(Array 2) [4, 5]
(Array 2) [6] => yields pair combination [4, 6] with 6 'spare'
=> 'spare' pair combination [2, 6] is a replication
# Move the lower of the bisected arrays along
(Array 1) [1, 2]
(Array 1)    [3] => yields pair combination [2, 3] with 1 'spare'
(Array 2) [4, 5]
(Array 2)    [6] => yields pair combination [5, 6] with 4 'spare'
=> 'spare' pair combination [1, 4] is a replication
```

This process above gives us 13 unique pairs, and then 2 that are non-unique. Every day of the week is covered, but we replicate.

Is there any way to do this more efficiently/to avoid the replication?

Comment: Sorry, but I am having hard time to understand your question. Are you asking how to generate as much non-repeating pairs out of 6 elements as possible?

Comment: Yes, I'm really uncertain of what you're asking. I cannot follow the process above, or what a "spare" is. Can you give us a clear, unambiguous *output* that you're after, based on the input of `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`?

Comment: I have a related question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477767/efficiently-partition-a-set-into-all-possible-unique-pair-combinations

Answer (score 2):

This is a round robin tournament where every player plays every other player. Line up the players like below to form the pairs 1 4, 2 5 and 3 6:

123
456

fix player 1, rotate the remaining players:

**1**42
563

to produce pairs 1 5, 4 6 and 2 3. Keep rotating:

**1**54
632

**1**65
324

**1**36
 245

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you're simply after the built-in [`combination`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-combination) method which returns an enumerator. You can use `.to_a` to turn it into an array of unique combinations.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].combination(2).to_a
# => [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [2, 6], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [4, 5], [4, 6], [5, 6]]
```

Comment: I think that he also want them grouped in 5 groups of 3 non-overlapping pairs.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a [1-factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_factorization). One 1-factorization of the complete graph on 6 vertices {0,1,2,3,4,oo} is to let the schedule on day i be {{oo,i},{i+1,i+4},{i+2,i+3}} where all of the numbers i+j are reduced mod 5.